# Can't find the logout+shutdown menu

Tags: 10.04, gnome-panel, menu

I removed the by default rightmost menu from the panel (the one allowing [logout, reboot, shutdown, etc.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24/remove-online-status-menu-but-keep-the-logout-menu)) and can't find it in the "Add to Panel" menu. I'm using Ubuntu 10.4 with the GNOME Panel 2.30.2.

Comment: please can you add the version of ubuntu you are using and what desktop interface you are using e.g. unity/gnome-classic etc.  thanks.

Comment: @fossfreedom: I added the info to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The applet you are interested in is *Indicator Applet Session*

[image]